# Help animating a character

Tags: sketch-app, animation

My goal is to create a "bobbing" animation with a character I created. The character is attached below. (Suggestions on the character also welcome. :))

I'm new to graphic design and am not sure how to create this simple animation.

The goal is to have his lower body stationary while his torso and head bob up and down gradually, to breathe life into this static character, to make him feel alive.

After some Googling and reading some tutorials, I know most animations occur at 24-30 FPS. Does this mean I need to create 24-30 frames to simulate this bobbing? Or can I simply create a start frame and end frame then quickly alternate between the two frames?

I used Sketch to create this character.

[image]

Comment: You might look at this: http://animatemate.com/

Comment: @Scott Thank you very much, that's very helpful :)

Comment: I did write an answer for Photoshop... then realized you didn't want Photoshop, so I deleted it :) It could be done in Photoshop though ----- [Bouncy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zfU1.gif)

Comment: @scott haha actually photoshop is even better(i am new to sketch but more familiar with PS.. My concern is if I use PS, the animation won't be very consistent since I need to draw frame by frame)  Do you have any better way to deal with it? Would you mind write the PS answer again? I will appreciate it a lot! :)

Comment: @Scott oh I just saw your Bouncy animation. Thank you so much for making it!! It is very close to what I want to make.

Answer (score 2):

In **Synfig Studio** [Open Source] you can rig a 2d character and animate .
You should take a look at that i guess.

[Synfig Studio Link -->](http://www.synfig.org/)

I  case if you are using Blender ..Also it is possible to rig a 2d character in blender as well.

Another 2d animation software with rigging .

[Dragon Bones](http://dragonbones.com/en/animation.html)

Once you rigged your character you can do any animations you like..

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much, will try this tools out:)